# ElementRef NativeElement getting changed when datepicker is clicked?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a directive, which I am expecting to trigger when I click outside of my angular 2 calendar.

the directive is:

```
    import {Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener} from 
     '@angular/core';

     @Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]'
      })
    export class ClickOutsideDirective {
    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    @Output()
    public clickOutside = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
    public onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
        if (!targetElement) {
            return;
        }

        const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(event);
        }
    }
   }
```

And my date picker is

```
 <div [hidden]="!isDatepickerOneVisible" class="datepicker-container"
    (clickOutside)="close($event)">
                    <datepicker [(ngModel)]="model.from" [minDate]="minDate" name="datepicker" (selectionDone)="onDateSelectionOneDone($event)">
                    </datepicker>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

I am expecting the close function to trigger when clicking outside of the date picker.

I am checking

this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);

In this condition.target element will be where I clicked and the native element is the div where I placed the directive attribute.

But when I click the month/year selector in date picker, when I click date picker UI will change(if I select month selector, it will take me to the date picker page of where all month is listed). what I  am expecting is get Native Element to be same always. but when I select month selector/year selector the native elements inner part(date picker part is getting changed).which will cause a problem for my logic.

I should get native element as where the current element where the directive attribute is placed. It should not change when I click on Month/Year selector.

How to fix this one?

instead of using

```
constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef)
```

can we pass _elementRef.nativeElement from UI?

See when click on june 2017 (month selector) [image]

i am expecting to get native element should contain date picker part which is shown in first image.

But in my native element instead off getting what in picture 1, i am getting what is in picture 2.
[image]